# When should I use \psgraph instead of \pspicture plus \psaxes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am new to PSTricks and want to plot some functions. The documentation of `pst-plot` explains (but not detailed enough) both `\psgraph` environment and the combination of `\pspicture` and `\psaxes`. The thing I want to know is:

*When should I use one rather than the other one?*

Bonus question: I want to change the font of the axis labels from text to math. How can we do that?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[]{->}(0,0)(-1,-2)(\psPiTwo,2){8cm}{6cm}
    % plotting 
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: @Werner: Thank you very much for the useful comment. It really solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Since they are interchangeable, there should be no problem using either one or the other.

You should be able to change the x/y labels using

```
\psset[pst-plot]{xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$}
```

Here is a complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot
\begin{document}
\psset[pst-plot]{xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$}
\begin{psgraph}[]{->}(0,0)(-1,-2)(\psPiTwo,2){8cm}{6cm}
    % plotting 
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```