# Differences between psgraph and pspicture when formatting axes

Tags: pst-plot

I'm working on the graph of a direction field of an ODE along with some of the solutions. As a starting point I used user2478's solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139114/differential-equation-direction-plot-with-pgfplots) running with `xelatex` which produces a graph with `axesstyle=frame` where the axis labels are missing.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-ode}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.1,1.1)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,Ox=-1,Oy=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psset{algebraic}
\psVectorfield[arrows=-](-0.9,-0.9)(0.9,0.9){ x^2+y^2-1 }
%y0_a=-0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%y0_b=0.0
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.0}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%y0_c=0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}

\psset{arrows=-,linewidth=1pt}%
\listplot[linecolor=red  ]{y0_a}
\listplot[linecolor=green]{y0_b}
\listplot[linecolor=blue ]{y0_c}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: no axis labels]

From what I read in [the documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/pst-plot/0), it should be possible to use the `xAxisLabelPos` and `yAxisLabelPos` options in `\psset`. According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100119/when-should-i-use-psgraph-instead-of-pspicture-plus-psaxes), `pspicture` and `psgraph` should be interchangeable but I can only get these to work when I use `psgraph` instead of `pspicture`, where the position of labels is off. I tried modifying it with `xlabelPos` and `ylabelPos` but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-ode}
\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic,xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$,xAxisLabelPos={-0.5cm,-1.1}, yAxisLabelPos={-1.1,-0.5cm}}
\begin{psgraph}[ticks=none,axesstyle=frame,xlabelPos=bottom,
xLabels={-1,,1},yLabels={-1,,1}](0,0)(-1,-1)(1,1){6cm}{6cm}

\psVectorfield[arrows=-](-0.9,-0.9)(0.9,0.9){ x^2+y^2-1 }
%y0_a=-0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%y0_b=0.0
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.0}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%y0_c=0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}

\psset{arrows=-,linewidth=1pt}%
\listplot[linecolor=red  ]{y0_a}

\listplot[linecolor=green]{y0_b}
\listplot[linecolor=blue ]{y0_c}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image: wrong label positions]

What is the best way to get both the label positions for ticks from the top picture and the axis labels of the bottom one?